# Search for duplicates in texts with math equations

Tags: math, latex, similarity

My employer asked me to do a project for our local team. Actually, it will be a way to help our work to finished faster.

We have a local database where we add exercises divided in two fields. The question and the solution. My employer wants since we are a team and we work at the same time, to create a system like stackoverflow's similar questions. When one of the team tries to submit a new data in the database, then it will check if there are other fields which may be duplicates.

The reason he asked me is because I have done something similar in the past but only for text using techniques like TF-IDF and Latent Semantic Analysis. But now, since the math symbols are all in Latex, I cannot find a way to check for duplicates.

I have tried to apply TF-IDF to the text only, but it doesn't work.

Any suggestion?

**Edit:**
Sorry for the broad topic. I will try to give more examples about my problem.

All the texts are exercises of primary and secondary schools. It is a mix of text and numbers-equations-symbols. If there were only text, I could use TF-IDF to find possible duplicates. Now, several exercises have a little or are without text.

Examples:

1) a. Solve the following equation: (x+1)*(x-1) = 5

b. Find the x: x^2 - 1 = 5

They are the same equation but with a different expression. So, I don't want to mark them as duplicates.

2) a. Solve the following equation: 3x + 7 = 12

b. Find the solution: 7 + 3x = 12

c. Find the x: 3x = 12 - 7

a and b should be duplicate whereas the c will not be.

Answer (score 2):

You could try using [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/) to convert the LaTeX equation into MathML an XML format. You could then use tools to examine that structure. There are probably a few other tools which can convert your equation into some kind of tree structure.

Equality of mathematical expressions is a complex problem. There are question that should you treat (x+1)*(x-1) as being equal to x^2-1, algebraically they are the same.

You might want to investigate computer algebra systems which have a lot of sophisticated features for manipulating expressions.

One technique is to evaluate the expression at a number of points. If the values agree then its a good indication that the expressions are the same.

It might be easier to give a better answer if there was some idea of the type of problems you are working with, polynomials, integrals etc.?